# What is the best way to know if a QObject name was changed

Tags: c++, qt

QObject::setObjectName method is not virtual.
No specific signals are emitted when the setObjectName call is made.

Comment: Maybe it's a sign to you that changing of it is a bad idea ? :)

Comment: @N1ghtLight `objectName` is just a property, why would changing it be a bad idea?

Comment: I think that you're using the object name for something more than it was ever meant to be. The intent of the object name is that the name stays constant. If want a custom property, well, use the custom property mechanism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Qt 5, there's a [objectNameChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#signals) signal. But not in Qt 4.